# what does 26 mean in h.264?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding

Whenever I searched about `H.264`, there is plenty information about video-encoding, media-container so forth, but why I can not find any effective source to explain what is meaning of `26` in `H.26{1,2,3,4,5}`?

Comment: `26` doesn't have any special meaning - other than being two first digits of `261` standard. Which, in turn, was the first member of the H.26x family of video coding standards [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.261).

Comment: exactly, 26 does not have any special meaning, so why not call those H.37x, or 26 was chosen in random way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other H.26x are H Series recommendations of ITU-T (ITU Telecommunication Standardization Sector), series on [Audiovisual and multimedia systems](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H/en).

> H.261 Video codec for audiovisual services at p x 64 kbit/s
>   H.262 Information technology - Generic coding of moving pictures and associated audio information: Video
>   H.263 Video coding for low bit rate communication
>   H.Imp263 Implementors' Guide for ITU-T Recommendation H.263
>   H.264 Advanced video coding for generic audiovisual services
>   H.264.1 Conformance specification for ITU-T H.264 advanced video coding
>   H.264.2 Reference software for ITU-T H.264 advanced video coding
>   H.Imp264 Implementors' Guide for ITU-T Recommendation H.264
>   H.265 High efficiency video coding
>   H.265.1 Conformance specification for ITU-T H.265 high efficiency video coding
>   H.265.2 Reference software for ITU-T H.265 high efficiency video coding

However there are lot of others there so 26 alone does not have any special meaning.

[ITU-T Recommendations by series](https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/index.aspx?ser=H) gives another view on how the recommendations are structured:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I'm wondering, where are 25X and 24X, if there is only 26X, why called so, why not call it 37X, there must be reason, I'm not sure 26 is random number here

Comment: 24x and 25x exist too. 26x is not random, it's just a subrange starting at 260.